# Hazelcast AWS ECS configuration

Tags: hazelcast

Can't configure the Hazelcast cluster in AWS ECS environment.

```
"exception": "java.lang.NullPointerException: null\n\tat com.org.HazelcastConfiguration.setHzInstance(HazelcastConfiguration.java:40) [20 skipped]\n\tat com.org.player.PlayerServerApplication.main(PlayerServerApplication.java:86) [129 skipped]\n [8 skipped]\nWrapped by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to configure discovery strategies\n\tat com.org.HazelcastConfiguration.setHzInstance(HazelcastConfiguration.java:40) [11 skipped]\n\tat com.org.player.PlayerServerApplication.main(PlayerServerApplication.java:86) [129 skipped]\n [8 skipped]\n",
```

using the awsvpc network mode for the ECS task with the following configuration
[image]

terraform policy doc

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "hazelcast_policy_doc" {
statement {
actions = [
  "ecs:*"
  ]

resources = ["*"]
```

}
}

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the reported issues on the github. Fixed by setting the current region via env variable.

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/22100